# How to log in root project with Log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I want to log in my project, but it is logging on my desktop by default.
How can I fix it ?

Here are the `log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, FILE
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-5p] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/joss.log

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-5p] (%F:%M:%L) %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the problem, it was because of this :

[image]

In Tomcat run configurations, you can specify the working folder, which is normally parameter inside some Tomcat conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `log4j.appender.FILE.File` where you want to save location.

I think your project is located at your desktop so `log4j` is logging on your desktop because your `log4j.properties` is written by `logs/joss.log`

**AS-IS**

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=logs/joss.log
```

**TO-BE**

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/LOGGING_FILES_DIRECTORY/LOG_FILE_NAME.log
```

or just change from `absolute path` to `relative path` like below properties value. Then the log file(=joss.log) will be saved in your project directory([project root]/logs/joss.log).

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=./logs/joss.log
```

Comment: That 's what I did but it still create the log file on the desktop when I use

Comment: @JosselinDouineau Then, could you edit `log4j.appender.FILE.File` to absolute path instead of relative path? For example, `log4j.appender.FILE.File=C:/logs/test_log.log`